# how to ssh into an openstack instance from an outside network?

Tags: openstack, devstack

I have installed devstack in a single physical machine. I have already added ICMP rule and TCP rule on port 22 in openstack security group, therefore I can ssh into the instance from the same physical machine that is not a problem. What i want is to ssh into the Openstack instance from a different machine within the same network.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Provider network**:
If an instance is created using provider network IPs, you can access the instance from outside of the tenant/project.

Comment: I can ping my laptop from the instance terminal, but i can't ping the floating ip associated with the instance from my laptop, it says host unreachable.The floating ip(192.168.1.236) exists on my network maybe that's why it's saying host unreachable cause when I ping my floating ip I think it is trying to ping the same ip on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: Ping laptop from instance:
INSTANCE --> ARP --> LAPTOP.
LAPTOP --> ARP(Reply) --> INSTANCE

Case 2: Ping instance from laptop ,not working because ARP resolution failed.
LAPTOP --> ARP --> Failed

Solution: 
Use free IP(in your subnet).